# List of objects inheriting a generic class

Tags: c#, list, generics

I have a generic class for all the managers that are in my framework. (Managers for entites, game alarms, physics, and particles for example).

Essentially they all do the same thing. They have a collection of things, they need to update those things, and they need to render those things (Well, not all managers need to render..but anyway). So I've got a generic base class that does exactly that. I define what 'things' it stores.

```
public class GenericManager<T> where T : Updatable
```

And objects in my game like entities/particles/etc inherit Updatable and away we go.

```
public class EntityManager : GenericManager<Entity>
```

and ofcourse, Entity is

```
public class Entity: Updatable
```

Now I am wondering how I would put all these managers into a list of managers. I need a way to store them all, iterate over them, and update them in yet another manager (I suppose).

*PS This may not be an ideal way to handle what I am doing but this is really just a learning exerciser for me to get more comfortable with using generics.*

Comment: This is extremely confusing. `EntityManager<Entity>` does not appear to have any relation to `GenericManager<T>`, and it declares a type parameter of the same name as a class. This is a bizarre and error-prone way to do this; are you sure that you didn't mean to do `class EntityManager : GenericManager<Entity>` ???

Comment: I've fixed the example up. sorry for the confusion..its been a long day

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could do with just a simple empty manager interface to create the list and intersections based on the [OfType](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb360913.aspx) extension method, like this

```
public interface IGenericManager { }

public class GenericManager<T> : IGenericManager where T : Updateable { }

public class EntityManager : GenericManager<Entity> { }

var list = new List<IGenericManager>();
var entityManagers = list.OfType<EntityManager>();
```

Answer (score 1):

Declare `IGenericManager` interface, let `GenericManager<T> : IGenericManager` and you can use `List<IGenericManager>`.

The only drawback is that the methods exposed cannot be generic.

**UPDATE:**

```
interface IGenericManager
{
    Type ManagerType { get; }
}

GenericManager<T> : IGenericManager
{
    public Type ManagerType { get { return typeof(T) ; } }
}
```

Comment: lets say i am searching for my entitymanager in my list of managers. would there be a way to distinguish which object is which?

Comment: Updated answer - you can now do (pseudo-code): `List<IGenericManager>().Single(x => x.ManagerType == myType)`

Comment: how about List<IGenericManager>().OfType<EntityManager>() ?

Answer (score 0):

You can extract generic interface for you base generic manager and make it covariant:

```
public class GenericManager<T> :IGenericManager<T> where T : Updatable { }

public interface IGenericManager<out T> where T : Updatable { }

public class Updatable { }

class UpdatableX : Updatable {}

class UpdatableY : Updatable {}
```

After that you'll be able to put all your stuff into the `List<IGenericManager<Updatable>>`:

```
var list = new List<IGenericManager<Updatable>>
    {new GenericManager<UpdatableX>(), new GenericManager<UpdatableY>()};
```

**UPDATE**: Forgot to mention, it's possible only in .NET framework 4, because in previous versions generics couldn't be covariant or contravariant.

Comment: must do some poking around but will get back to this shortly..think this is more what i am after, even though Jakub's solution was nice.

Comment: is the interface really necessary? why not directly apply covariance to the template argument of GenericManager?

Comment: It is. You can't use variant parameters in a class, only in interface or delegate.